# Unable to call function with CreateRemoteThread

Tags: dll-injection, byte-code, shellcode, injection

I am messing around with some dll injection/code injection. Therefore I made a little program which does nothing, but it has a function in it, which never get called and I wrote another program which injects code into the first which should call that function.

Here is my program which injects the code (only relevant part is shown):

```
BYTE codeCave[15] = {
        0xFF, 0x74, 0x24, 0x04, //PUSH DWORD PTR:[ESP+04]
        0x88, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,   //MOV EAX, 0x0  (0x0 is the address of the function)
        0xFF, 0xD0, //CALL EAX
        0x83, 0xC4, 0x04,   //ADD ESP, 0x04
        0xC3    //RETN
    };

    DWORD offset = 0x00014D80;
    DWORD funcAdr = offset + myLib.getBaseAdress();
    memcpy(&codeCave[5], &funcAdr, 4);

    char testString[] = "I called the function.";

    int stringlen = strlen(testString) + 1; //+1 for \0 at the end
    int caveLen = sizeof(codeCave);
    int fullLen = caveLen + stringlen;

    LPVOID remoteString = myLib.allocateMemoryInProcess(fullLen);
    if (remoteString == NULL) {
        printf("FAILED");
        return 1;
    }
    LPVOID remoteCave = (LPVOID)((DWORD)remoteString + stringlen);
    myLib.writeMemory((LPVOID)remoteString, testString);
    myLib.writeMemory((LPVOID)remoteCave, codeCave);
    printf("%x\n", funcAdr);
    printf("%x\n", remoteCave);
    getchar();
    myLib.createThread((LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)remoteCave, remoteString);
```

With:

```
LPVOID allocateMemoryInProcess(int length) {
    return VirtualAllocEx(gameHandle, 0, length, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE);
}
```

and:

```
void createThread(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE startAdr, LPVOID arg) {
    HANDLE thread = CreateRemoteThread(gameHandle, NULL, NULL, startAdr, arg, NULL, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(thread);
}
```

The "funcAdr" is the address I want to call in the other program, it is right as I print it out and opened it up in ollydbg:

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
00034D80  /$  55            PUSH EBP                                 ; ListTest.print(string)
00034D81  |.  8BEC          MOV EBP,ESP
00034D83  |.  81EC C0000000 SUB ESP,0C0
00034D89  |.  53            PUSH EBX
00034D8A  |.  56            PUSH ESI
00034D8B  |.  57            PUSH EDI
00034D8C  |.  8DBD 40FFFFFF LEA EDI,[EBP-0C0]
00034D92  |?  B9 30000000   MOV ECX,30
00034D97  |?  B8 CCCCCCCC   MOV EAX,CCCCCCCC
00034D9C  |?  F3:AB         REP STOS DWORD PTR ES:[EDI]
00034D9E  |?  68 28BC0300   PUSH OFFSET 0003BC28                     ; ASCII "TROLOLOLO"
00034DA3  |.  E8 61C8FFFF   CALL 00031609
00034DA8  |?  83C4 04       ADD ESP,4
00034DAB  |?  8B45 08       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
00034DAE  |?  50            PUSH EAX
00034DAF  |?  E8 55C8FFFF   CALL 00031609
00034DB4  |.  83C4 04       ADD ESP,4
00034DB7  |?  5F            POP EDI
00034DB8  |?  5E            POP ESI
00034DB9  |?  5B            POP EBX
00034DBA  |.  81C4 C0000000 ADD ESP,0C0
00034DC0  |?  3BEC          CMP EBP,ESP
00034DC2  |?  E8 5AC4FFFF   CALL 00031221
00034DC7  |.  8BE5          MOV ESP,EBP                              ; |
00034DC9  |?  5D            POP EBP                                  ; |
00034DCA  |?  C3            RETN                                     ; |
00034DCB  |?  CC            INT3                                     ; |
00034DCC  |?  CC            INT3                                     ; |
```

The function which I want to call from my second program simply receives a const char* and prints it.

```
void print(const char* string) {
    printf("TROLOLOLO");
    printf(string);
}
```

If I run the above code I receive following error:
[image]

If I however change my print function in the first application so that it doesn't receive any argument and I call "funcAdr" directly through .createThread it works without problems though.

Can you guys maybe help me and tell me where I have something wrong?

Comment: One issue I spotted is that `remoteCave` points to the *end* of the allocated buffer, instead of it's begining.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot add a comment I will post it here:

@NirIzr :
Well it doesn't actually point to the end, does it?
It should point to the memory where the actual byte array starts. Note that I first write the testString into the memory of my second program then the bytecode.
Then I do remoteCave = (LPVOID)((DWORD)remoteString + stringlen) which should then be the start of the bytecode.

EDIT: Okey I found the answer...I had an error in my byte buffer. I needed to change the 0x88 from my second line to 0xB8.

Comment: If this is an answer you feel comfortable with you should mark it as Accepted Answer by clicking the V button below the up/down vote buttons.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that already, but I cannot seem to find a button to accept the answer? Can maybe a mod or someone mark it?